# How can I change resource file using Xcode build settings

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to control which resource files should be included in a release package using Xcode setting etc?

I have resource files for each languages, and they are very large.
So I want to include resource files for only one language to reduce each release file size.

I heard that I can have multiple info.plist if I duplicate Target using Xcode.
Is that applicable for resource files also?

Thank you,

Comment: By using multiple build targets you can add resources to specific targets. Or you exchange the resources after build and resign your application with `codesign`.

Comment: The problem with different resources for different languages is, what happens if the user changes his language to one not included in the bundle?